# I've already generated my debugging SHA-1 but still i am getting this error

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

> This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ App validation failed ]

I've already generated my debugging SHA-1 and paste it to my firebase app but still i am getting this error.

Comment: did u follow all the necessary steps like adding gradle plugins in build.gradle file etc

Comment: Make sure your project is using AndroidX.If not you can create a new project using flutter create --androidx yourprojectname. Check for google-services.json file.It should be placed in app folder and also download and replace the latest file after adding finerprints.Do a flutter clean and reinstall the app.

Comment: Check this answer if it works https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/355#issuecomment-625185786